# MEDIA_ROOT django read and delete

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django application, which permits to manage music files (upload, read, delete, ...).

I'm using MEDIA_ROOT system for the music uploads, which works perfectly ! 
But, to read or delete a file in MEDIA_ROOT, I don't know ... (except with variable in script..).

For example, if I need to read a music with Mplayer, my actual solution in views.py :

```
media_root = "/home/music/"
command = ("sudo /usr/bin/mplayer "+media_root)
path = music.path
p = subprocess.Popen(command+str(music.path), shell=True)
```

Is there any (secure) way to access to the MEDIA_ROOT from views.py / models.py ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the settings by simply doing

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.MEDIA_URL
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code